# How does a redox reaction between NaClO and KBr take place? will bromide be oxidised to bromine?

Tags: redox

How does a redox reaction between $\ce{NaClO}$ and $\ce{KBr}$ take place?

will bromide be oxidised to bromine?

$\ce{2Br^{−} + ClO^{−} + H2O ⟶ Cl^{−} + 2 OH^{−} + Br2}$

or will bromide be oxidised to $\ce{BrO^{−}}$?

$\ce{Br^{−} + ClO^{−} ⟶ BrO^{−} + Cl^{−}}$